# How to change ListView item when contact online/offline in android asmack

Tags: android

I'm try to make android chat using asmack then Im using RosterListener i need to change Presence in each user but my code has an Exception I cant find whats the reason about that

**please help me**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence.Mode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.VCard;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.VCardProvider;

import com.ices.hc.f2f.R;
import com.ices.hc.f2f.ent.comm.UserModel;
import com.ices.hc.f2f.ext.ChatListAdapter;
import com.ices.hc.f2f.tmp.Mem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ActivityMyProfile extends Activity implements RosterListener {
    private ListView onlineList;
    private ChatListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);
        getActionBar().hide();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        onlineList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.profile_online_list);

        adapter = new ChatListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.online_list_item, getOnlineList());
        onlineList.setAdapter(adapter);
        onlineList.setClickable(true);
    }

    private ArrayList<UserModel> getOnlineList() {
        final ArrayList<UserModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

        final Roster roster = Mem.getConnection().getRoster();
        for (RosterEntry entry : roster.getEntries()) {
            byte[] avater = getAvater(entry.getUser());
            Presence presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
            int userState = retrieveState(presence.getMode(),
                    presence.isAvailable());

            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(avater, 0, avater.length));
            if (drawable == null) {
                drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user_gray);
            }
            arrayList.add(new UserModel(drawable, entry.getName(), entry
                    .getUser(), userState));

        }
        roster.addRosterListener(this);
        return arrayList;
    }

    public int retrieveState(Mode userMode, boolean isOnline) {
        int userState = android.R.drawable.presence_offline;
        if (userMode == Mode.dnd) {
            userState = android.R.drawable.presence_busy;
        } else if (userMode == Mode.away || userMode == Mode.xa) {
            userState = android.R.drawable.presence_away;
        } else if (isOnline) {
            userState = android.R.drawable.presence_online;
        }
        return userState;
    }

    private byte[] getAvater(String user) {
        VCard vCard = new VCard();
        SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(300000);
        ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp",
                new VCardProvider());
        try {
            vCard.load(Mem.getConnection(), user);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
        }

        byte[] avatar = vCard.getAvatar();
        if (avatar == null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_user_gray);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();
            return bitMapData;
        }

        return avatar;
    }

    @Override
    public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

here is Exception

```
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023): Exception in packet listener
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6006)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.clearChildFocus(ViewRootImpl.java:2787)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:790)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:790)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:790)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:790)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:790)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.View.clearFocusInternal(View.java:4711)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.View.clearFocus(View.java:4694)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.ViewGroup.clearFocus(ViewGroup.java:803)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8855)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.view.View.setFocusable(View.java:6077)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:719)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:813)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6280)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:261)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at com.ices.hc.f2f.vie.ActivityMyProfile.presenceChanged(ActivityMyProfile.java:131)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster.fireRosterPresenceEvent(Roster.java:659)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster.access$700(Roster.java:50)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster$PresencePacketListener.processPacket(Roster.java:720)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection$ListenerWrapper.notifyListener(Connection.java:858)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$ListenerNotification.run(PacketReader.java:456)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-28 23:52:24.481: E/PacketReader(1023):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you have a separate thread trying to update something on the UI, you cannot do that. You can only update the UI from the UI thread

Comment: yes, tyczj is rite I think problem is in this line new Thread(getUser(arrayList, avater, entry, userState)).start();

Comment: after ur advice I was change my code in same thread but it has a same exception

Comment: what do you mean you "changed you code in the same thread" update your question with what you changed